# angular directive ngModel change on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create directive which update real model only on needed cases. Let's say I want to update input value only on blur. I added canChange variable to check if I can update model value and I set this variable to true on blur. I also want to run my custom viewValue transform called myChangeFn. I don't know why  ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue); is not triggering my parser if I add some text and blur input. I know I can use ngModelOptions, but in my case it will not work, because where is some case when I want to change model value on other events.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

}).directive('changeOnBlur', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

          var canChange = false;

          ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
             var val =  canChange ? myChangeFn(value) : ctrl.$modelValue;
             canChange = false;
             return val;
          });

          function myChangeFn(value) {
            return value + 'my custom data';
          }

          element.on('blur', function() {
            canChange = true;
            ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
          });


        }
    }
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qrR6MgW0c6kUx71Hp17A?p=preview

Comment: As I said I have cases when I need to update model value on over events not only on blur, maybe my question title is not correct, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to bind your model to the directive as an attribute:

//JavaScript

```
scope: {
    vm : '='
},
```

// HTML

```
<input ng-model="time" change-on-blur vm="time" />
```

Now you can access the model and manipulate it how ever you want in the directive as `scope.vm`.

I know this isn't the solution you're looking for but it might set you on the right path to finding it.

Comment: Yes, I implemented it by adding vm to scope